# C# Print PDF using the Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library

Tags: c#, acrobat-sdk

I'm using the Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library. I would like to print the PDF to a new file and specify the output file and location.

I have the following code. But don't see a Print method on the AcroPDDoc object.

```
    Acrobat.AcroApp app = new AcroApp();
   
    AcroPDDoc doc = new AcroPDDoc();

    doc.Open("C:\\Temp\\MyPDF.pdf");

    doc. PRINT ??????   HOW?
```

And how can I specify the output file?

thx in advance

Comment: At least according to the acrobat-sdk tag wiki, that library is JavaScript only. What nuget package are you using, or where did you obtain the assembly you're using?

Comment: Interop.Acrobat     -  Adobe Acrobat 10. Type Library    File Type Active X